Would radar/sonar/other spy technology be able to penetrate space station walls?
Cue the song from Avatar: the Last Airbender, because my world's habitable deep space station is absolutely riddled with Secret Tunnels. The following constraints apply:

The design of said station is largely composed of metal, similar in construction to the ISS or similar modern extraterrestrial implements.
The tunnels are difficult to locate for those who don't know the entrances, and similar to a labyrinth in their complexity and general un-user-friendliness.
The station is presently inhabited by a hostile party while five refugees hide out in the tunnels.
The device used for detection would most likely be employed from inside the station by foot soldiers.

With these material and situational specifications, assuming a fairly technologically advanced civilization (capable of space travel, extreme military strength, but reasonably near-future in terms of tools and capabilities), would the refugees within these reinforced aluminum/titanium tunnels be discoverable via slightly-better-than-average sonar, radar, lidar, or similar extant penetrating "spy" technology at the disposal of a small interstellar regiment?

Do I understand correctly that the station is occupied by a defending force and the five stowaways, and it's the job of the attacking force to detect the stowaways for whatever reason?

Based on the "ping back" nature of the technologies you're referencing, you're effectively asking for a signal that reliably reflects off of refugees, but not the space station or the hostile party. This is going to require establishing how these are materially different. Your question doesn't really indicate the finer points like if these refugees could intentionally be carrying some kind of detector that the technology would identifiably pick up, or if the refugees are unprepared for being detected and people are trying to come up with a detection method ad hoc (with no prep time)

How many microphones, micro-seismometers, CO2, Temperature sensors can you deploy? Do the stowaways need to access common areas for food, water and/or ablutions? It's hard to see rats behind the walls but you can hear or feel them scratching around and you can see them when they try to sneak food. If the stowaways congregate you'd be able to detect their localised area getting warmer and depleting oxygen/increasing CO2. If you're the occupying commander what's stopping you from doing a full depressurization and/or chemical treatment with your force safely on their lifeboats/transport craft? Th

This question needs clarification on whether the detection device would be on board the space station, or outside it in space.

@jpa clarified! I believe it would be inside the station as fine maneuvers in space can be tricky at best and, well, we have quite a surplus of in-station infantry at our disposal.

Directly addressing your question...

Radar: probably not. While ground penetrating radar is a thing, the reality is that as the density of something you're pointing the radar at increases, the ability of the radar to penetrate it decreases. This is actually the point of using radar. Worse, space stations will be engineered to some degree to protect the interior from the various radiation spectra of space. In other words, it's hard for me to believe radar could solve your problem.

If you thought radar was bad... sonar is a fancy acronym that translates to, "use sound waves just like you would radar for exactly the same purpose." Now, modern submarine tactics does a lot more listening than it once did, but the essence of sonar is that cheerful "ping!"... a sound sent out to bounce off something. The problem is the word "sound." Sound only exists in an atmosphere or medium like water that can transport a compression wave (which our ear translates into "sound"). Space is fundamentally a vacuum, so there's no sound in space, so there's no sonar.

Lidar is the laser-based version of radar and it suffers more than radar does. It could penetrate something transparent to the wavelength of light used for the laser (e.g., a window), but otherwise it's worse than radar.


What that might... maybe... leave you is thermal imaging.
While it's true that space ships and space stations could be reasonably expected to insulate the walls, one of the more cheerful problems with space travel is ridding the ship of excess heat. In other words, you need insulation where things like humans are to keep them from freezing, but otherwise you're trying to get rid of it. This suggests the possibility of seeing the interior using thermal imaging in that walls will have a different temperature than the atmosphere in a hall or room. In other words, it's believable that it could be made to work.
But only to a degree. The deeper you go, the messier the image gets because you really can't look past the thermal emissions closer to the surface. It's a change of focus, but the mess is still there getting in the way of what you're trying to see. But this is a good thing! Stories with "perfect solutions" are boring. You want limits and weaknesses.

A maser could do, if there would be a wavelength that the station's surface would pass through - microwaves have a lot less energy per quantum to cause direct troubles; but anyway anything radar suffers from distance^(-4) modifier to received power, so catching reflection from semi-transparent medium at significant distance would be very hard. But thermal emission detection is off, unless the refugees are somewhere VERY close to the outer space border of the station, AND are actively heating its outer wall in hopes of sending a signal that there's someone wanting to be rescued.

@Vesper Now a maser is a possibility! I'm concerned with the radiation shielding and the fact that microwaves are included... but I think it's as believable as thermal imaging.

Nitpick: It is not only that you need penetration, you also need NOT penetration (rebounds) from the objects you want to identify. A neutrino would happily pass through the space station walls, but it would also pass through the persons in it, so you would get no return signal. So if you get a radar signal that penetrates the wall, it will not be useful to detect the people.

I think that the main problem here is that a space station is basically a bunker floatign in vacuum: it is designed to be heavily shielded against every kind of energy (from kinetic impacts to, most importantly, radiation). If your emitter (of radio waves, microwaves, light, vibrations, Power of Love, whatever) is more powerful than the shielding designed (likely: over-designed by a great margin) to protect human beings, then the emitter is a weapon of mass destruction. Or put it differently, if it can pierce the shielding, it will cook the humans inside, or at least give them cancer.

Thermal imaging won't work. The walls are insulated and the heat is disposed through specialized heat sinks. You won't see IR signatures through the walls, else they would cook whatever is inside when that section was facing the Sun. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Active_Thermal_Control_System

@MindwinRememberMonica I'm not entirely convinced (although I did say What that might... maybe... leave you...). I've seen modern thermal imaging look through insulated buildings. It's a question of how much insulation and how the excess heat is transported for disposal. I grant that it's unlikely, but I don't believe it's impossible. Hence my answer.

@jbh Cameras that see IR light can see through things that are see-through to IR light. Titanium is not one of those things. A TIC pointed at a sheet of titanium will measure the emissions of the sheet of titanium, not the emissions of anything behind it. Also, almost all images of TICs looking through walls are fiction (i.e. stuff that only works in the movies), mislabeled (you may have seen images of wall-penetrating radar, which also wouldn't work through titanium, but works just fine through wood and fiberglass), or just outright lies to get clicks or sell gadgets.

@gs Now THAT'S a good point.

If your neighbor builds a house out of silicon, sapphire, and table salt, you can probably spy on him with your TIC, though. Unless he paints it.

'Sonar' isn't totally out of the question, you could use a laser microphone and use laser ablation or chuck a pebble at it to generate your 'ping'. Or just do passive sonar.

If there are people inhabiting the station and other people inhabiting the tunnels, then the station itself as well as the secret tunnels are filled with atmosphere. Couldn't you still use sonar inside the station? The question didn't say the detection had to be done from outside the station, especially given that the hostile forces are occupying it.

@patstew A combination of technologies like you suggest would make a great answer!

@Idran That's the genius of Patstew's comment. Yes, you could use sonar inside the station... but you still need to get the information to someone outside the station and we're dealing with spytech, meaning whatever solution is chosen can't be easily detected.

The oldest spy technology of all: send somebody to take a look and report back. Only it's the future, so we do it with an autonomous drone the size of an iPhone, and we have thousands of them in the regimental arsenal. Metal walls means we won't be able to communicate with them by radio until (unless) they come back, unless the space station is wired for wifi. But we know which ones were sent with what pathing instructions, so if one doesn't come back, we know how to find the enemy that killed it.
Radar and Lidar are no-go under these constraints. Radios will also not be usable. Conductive (metal) walls are opaque reflectors at any of the plausibly usable frequencies, which is why you don't cook your face every time you use the microwave oven. (And at the implausible frequencies, you'd just be giving everybody cancer, not detecting anybody.) If you want to use ground-penetrating / wall-penetrating radar, or radio, make your interior walls out of non-conductive materials, like plastic sheeting on a metal frame.
For Sonar, the detector and emitter will obviously have to be attached to the space station itself, since in space, nobody can hear you ping. Even then, you won't get anything resembling a picture, just a confused mess. However, if your plot calls for it, you could have an arbitrarily sophisticated AI input an arbitrarily high fidelity confused mess and output probable locations of bodies.
Speaking of wifi, if the space station is wired for wifi, the wifi network knows where every device that's connected to the wifi network is, down to the nearest repeater.
(We don't just replace the soldiers with bigger drones because we're afraid of Skynet or something... everybody knows the real reason is because you want to write and the reader wants to read a story about Marines in Space, and we've all already agreed to not worry about it.)

You can even use the drones to set up a Wifi mesh network. Leaves the question open how the drones get into the station, but if they can get in, they can leave behind relay drones that keep the connection open. Question is whether the author assumes the hostile party will pick up the signals, which depends on their abilities and motives.

Heat, power, oxygen & CO2 etc. (The ledger is off)
All space stations are sealed environmental systems with very narrow tolerances in terms of their carrying capacity. For example water and air needs constant recycling/filtering and replenishment. Importantly, waste heat is also a critical issue because in the vacuum of space the heat generated by both equipment and people needs to be managed & removed from the station by cooling systems so that it can be radiated radiated away into space. The key point is that the management of ALL of these processes is done via computer monitoring a host of different sensors scattered throughout the station. These sensors monitor temperature, humidity, atmospheric pressure and composition plus water & power consumption in different parts of the station as well as waste water processing. And this is done section by section, compartment by compartment. Every hallway and crawl way, every workspace module will be monitored and their inputs/outputs measured.
All of the above also means that just like a ship a space station will be designed with a maximum crew capacity that it can sustain long term. And any significant number of 'hidden refugees' are going the strain the capacity of the station beyond design levels. And even if they grow their own food they'll still consume air, water and power and generate a LOT of waste heat while doing so.
So the stations monitoring systems are going to notice the extra loads being placed on it (even if the stowaways  turn off any sensors in their hidden compartments). And they'll also notice which areas of the station are generating the unexpectedly high consumption and waste levels. This WILL cause the legitimate crew to start conducting physical inspections of the station because they're own survival depends on it. It also won't take them long to figure out that there are other people on board based on the type of resource drains and excess outputs of 'waste' they're seeing over time.
Once they start looking? Physical examination and the cross-checking of measurements taken by the crew against the Station's schematics will start to reveal anomalies in the errors identified by the Station' sensors.  Physical disassembly of internal panels and walls will follow in short as will examination of the spaces concerned with portable x-ray machines and thermal camera's and yes even sonar (if they can build them from parts) to identify hollow spaces/cavities. But even simple noise checks would help.
EDIT: Since I missed the bit about there being only 5 stowaways (me bad) So the stowaways will eventually be found. The only thing that might delay their discovery would be if say the Station was built to house 100 crew but was only being manned by a skeleton crew of for example 10 people when the stowaways arrived. If there was only a FIVE stowaways? They might get away with it for a while, but it would only be for a while. Because eventually the Station's systems and by default the crew would notice the higher than expected drains on the stations systems and the extra 'output' the stowaways were generating. Simply put the Stations 'ledger' wouldn't balance. The bigger the station (and crew size) the longer they might be able to hide. But the basic problem remains the same i.e. sensors everywhere and limited life support capabilities!

I may have misunderstood the OP, but my reading was that the station is occupied by a defending force and the five stowaways, and it's the job of the attacking force to detect the stowaways for whatever reason. As the colonel of the space marine regiment, I'd love it if the defending commander would send me a full and complete deployment roster and logistical system report, for, um. Humanitarian reasons, you see. There might be innocent civilians stowed away that you haven't detected, you see. The Space Geneva conventions, you see.

@gs i love everything about this comment

Radar: No
Radar is fully reflected by metals (or water), so it will not be able to penetrate anything. That said, it can be highly precise, and could theoretically detect vibrations caused by people walking or generally moving around. Similarly, due to the reflective nature, if you aimed a radar device down a long shaft of metal that has an elbow at the end, the radar would still be able to detect movement or change beyond the elbow because it reflects. This means, with a radar system, you could detect movement that is behind cover or not in direct line-of-sight, but you can't see through things.
Lidar: No
Lidar is basically a camera that measures depth. It can't see through anything, and it wouldn't be able to see anything a normal camera can't see.
Sonar: Not really, but sorta
The issue with sonar is that it does not do well when transitioning to a different medium. Like, a sonar that is being used underwater can "map" the shape of the water and where things in the water reflect, like submarines, but it can't effectively "map" the interior of the submarine or what is behind a reflective barrier. This is similar to radar, where you might be able to use a sonar device to detect changes in where things are in a room due to the sound waves reflecting off of surfaces, but you can't "see through" things.
That said, since one component of a sonar device is a very good microphone, you could use this to locate stowaways. In the near future, it would presumably be good enough to filter out known noises that the space station makes, and then all you'd be left with might be the heartbeats of those hiding in the secret tunnels. With a couple different microphones, these could then quickly be located (see "acoustic camera").
Thermal: Probably Not
Blocking the thermal radiation cast by humans is trivial. If they are behind metal, they won't be seen. Theoretically, if a human spends  a long time sitting in the same spot, and the wall they are leaning against is thin, it may heat up in the shape of their outline which could be spotted from a thermal camera, but it would have no chance of seeing through even moderately thick walls or locating people who move regularly. Would also be complicated by the fact that there are likely many things on a space station that are supposed to be hot (or cold) like life support equipment that move various fluids/gasses around.
X-Ray: Now we're getting somewhere
It is conceivable that in the near future a practical X-ray camera is developed. Using existing background radiation, or very low power X-ray illumination, you could see through thinner things with this. It would still be blocked by metal, but so long as it's a less dense/lighter metal like aluminum, you'd probably have some chance.
My observation
In any reasonable/realistic spaceship setting, every ship and space structure is going to be downright filled with all sorts of sensors. It costs basically nothing to include temperature probes, atmosphere checkers, radiation detectors, small cameras, etc basically everywhere, so on any ship that hasn't bee severely compromised by something like a cyberattack, it would be very hard to completely hide all the signs of one's presence.

I'd go on a limb and assume that a space station is going to be very, very, very thoroughly ruggedized against penetrating space radiation, specifically including X-rays, making x-ray scans next to useless. X-ray device powerful enough to go through the radiation shielding will either cook everyone inside or give them cancer.

@GoingDurden on the contrary actually, if the station is highly shielded from background radiation, even an extremely low power source could be used for illumination. Likely, the shielding would be on the outside only for mass/cost savings. Also, I think the radiation risk is overstated: this is the future, so what if they get a hefty dose? Just swallow your anti-cancer pills and go about your job like everyone else.

can you expand on that? My assumption was that if a station was shielded, X-rays (and other forms of radiation) would just bounce off the shielding giving you a very detailed 3d picture of the outer shell of the station, but not the insides. Kinda like trying to x-ray the head of someone wearing a lead helmet.  As for radiation risks, I assumed a hard sci-fi setting, in which mundane shielding is more plausible than anti-cancer pills.

@GoingDurden I interpreted the question as the "regiment" being deployed on the station and walking/floating around with handheld scanner units, searching for the refugees (otherwise sonar would make absolutely no sense). Also, I think that curing cancer is very reasonable for hard sci-fi. Like, I expect that all types of cancers will become curable within the next 50 years, although it might stay expensive.

oh ok sure. I interpreted this more as a scenario of a spaceship circling the station at a clandestine distance and beaming it with a powerful scanner. A cure that could defeat or prevent all kinds of cancer would be deep in the realm of transhumanist biotech not simple medicine, and thus a major world-building point, much greater than the space scanner.

sonar will depend on the type of sonar, low frequency sonar will not give you fine detail but it will penetrate the whole station and show voids, its what we use for underground imaging.

Yes and no.
We could hear whats talked inside the space station, by using the walls as a microphone via lasers. We could have a model build a comprehensive layout by detecting the forces applied inside the can and there directional vector. Me typing this on a laptop in the ISS, would apply a distinct pattern of small forces to a object attached to the iss, which then is countered by a teather, which applies the sum of all fingertip forces applied back to the ISS. You can see that.
Then there is the background radiation, which basically is a constant small-scale x-ray and particle-accelerator scanning. We have a neutrino image of the sun - filmed through earth now.  So it depends on the tech level.

We don't need any of this spy stuff.
Clearly they're hidden.  They've outfoxed us.  What can we do?

Turn off all the robots and equipment.
Leave the station.
Using your basic laser range finder at the docking port to see exactly where the station sits in space, relative to your pirate ship...
Wait for it to move.

Assuming you conscientiously turned down the life support to save energy, the rats in the walls won't stay still for long.  It's action and reaction.  Every maneuver they make is reflected in the movement of the station.  You can actually cross-reference the maps of the corridors with the sequence of motions to work out where they are likely to be.  The sound of the grenade going off when they hit the tripwire you left outside the life support center might also be a clue. :)
Drawback...
If you left some of the larger cargo robots in working order, and if you've let slip in an unguarded conversation what you intend, the rats can order them to raise/lower palettes of goods in exactly compensation for their own motions.  (They will need a secure comm link to the cargo hold)  In this way, the station will sit inert and pristine, but when you open the hatch, there's a crew of stowaways in stolen power armor toting C-14 Impaler rifles looking right back at you.

I see a StarCraft fan! More seriously, though, while your suggestion is theoretically accurate, I doubt this would work at the scales in question. Any measuring device has a margin of error in its readings, a limit to how precise it can be. The movements of a few people inside a decent-sized space station are simply too small to have a larger impact than your margin of error: bear in mind that your laser is mounted on something that itself suffers regular movements, and you can't feasibly calculate every microscopic movement. Cosmic background radiation can also affect your measurements, too.

People track the distance from Earth to Moon to the nearest millimeter - there was a planned experiment to improve this by a factor of 100, but it was cancelled for now I think.  When docking spacecraft commercially in the future, I don't think anyone will put up with an error beyond the length of a single wavelength of light (about half a micrometer).

Okay, that's more precise than I expected. Still, the movements of people inside a large space station are probably creating movements on the order of nanometres, if even that much. If your laser ranging is mounted on a spaceship (which is likely smaller than the space station), then you're trying to detect movements smaller than what your own ship's crew is causing.

The movements of your own ship can be cancelled out mathematically, assuming you have a little vacuum chamber somewhere with a free-floating interferometer that you use to monitor for any unexpected motions internally.  Regarding the station's motion, well, suppose it weighs 100 000 tonnes = 100 000 000 kg.  Then a 50 kg stowaway moving 2 m will move the station 2 mcm - still several full wavelengths of light on the interferometer.  If it's much heavier than that, the stowaway probably has to move more than 2 m.  There's a point where this fails, but not easily.

The fugitives would likely be found within a few days, using equipment likely on board both the interstellar spaceship and on the space station.  I would fully expect neutron radiography equipment (or any of the typical industrial radiography equipment) to be standard equipment.
Radiography devices would be invaluable in checking for potential failures in structural components.  Maintenance crews would likely scan the entire station regularly completely mapping all interior areas.  People would show up on these scans.
Depending on the structure of the space station, the devices could be a pair of drones that scan from the exterior or wheeled drones that scan by moving around the interior.
Industrial Radiography is currently being used to scan cargo containers.  One of the example images on the wikipedia page shows people in a cargo container.  I'd expect this technology to be much more accurate and able to scan larger areas.  The only option I can see for the fugitives would be to try to stay out of areas being scanned.  That said, once scanned the troops could use the generated map to sweep the tunnels.

Thank you so much for introducing this technology to me. How, exactly, does it work in practice, and by these ends would it be possible to defend against (for future more military contexts)?

A practical long term space station would be unlikely to be scanable by radiology equipment from the outside, as the radiation shielding would have to be opaque to this equipment in order to protect the crew from space radiation. And regular use of this equipment onboard would be questionable because of the increased radiation dose in what is already an elevated radiation environment.

Radiation shielding isn't an impenetrable barrier.  An interstellar vessel likely has more than enough power penetrate the station.  Mainly, though I would expect portable devices to be mandatory on space stations and space ships.  When it's on, it will be creating ionizing radiation, but the scanned areas won't be dangerous.  with a more advanced civilization will have better visualization abilities and better safety.

@Asterion iThere is a device that emits some form of energy that can be measured by the device on the other side.  There are tons of different penetrating rays that can be used all with different benefits and negatives.  More shielding would degrade the images some.  Moving away from the scanning areas would be best, but the tunnels would still be mapped.

If you don't need to see inside the tunnels, and just need to find there presence, then reflection seismology/UTM might work.
The principles behind reflection seismology and UTM is similar to sonar, only rather than looking at the reflections from where things are, you are looking at the reflections from where things aren't. This is counter intuitive, but reflections of sound waves aren't actually caused because the thing is solid, but because there is a difference in the wave propagation speed between a solid and air/water. This means that in addition to reflections from when waves hit a solid object in air/water, you also can get reflections when sound waves leave a solid object into air. Which means if you can emit chirps on into the walls of the space station, you can map out where the edges of the walls are. Which you can then translate into a map of the void spaces of the station.

worth noting sonar will work even better in a space station since the energy can't be dissipated to space,
